# Can I make a GPIO into a 3v output?

Tags: gpio, output

I am working on setting up a Pi3 and have a screen attached its currently taking up all the 3.3V outputs. Is it possible for me to change the settings on say GPIO 16 (pin 36) to become a 3.3V output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, change the GPIO to mode OUTPUT and write 1 (high).  The GPIO will then output 3V3 relative to ground.

Note that the GPIO will only safely supply about 16mA.

I should say that a better solution would be to tee-off power from one of the 3V3 power rail pins (perhaps by carefully soldering a wire to the underside of the board).

Comment: Thanks, i was able to set it to high and get my humidity sensors powerd!